# Styled alert system for javascript

Tags: javascript

i am using [smoke.js](http://ssssnakes.com/smoke/) which allows to style the classic alert javascript windows.

All you have to do is place `.smoke` before the alert ie. `smoke.confirm()`

The issue I am having is with the ok/cancel callback, it isnt working for me.

This is the example the website shows.

`You can implement these the same way you'd use the js alert()...just put "smoke." in front of it.

The confirm() replacement, however, needs to be used just a little differently:

```
smoke.confirm('You are about to destroy everything. Are you sure?',function(e){
    if (e){
        smoke.alert('OK pressed');
    }else{
        smoke.alert('CANCEL pressed');
    }
});
```

and the code I have is;

```
$(".upb_del_bookmark").click( function() {
        if(smoke.confirm(delete_message)) {
            var post_id = $(this).attr('rel');
            var data = {
                action: 'del_bookmark',
                del_post_id: post_id
            };
            $.post(upb_vars.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                $('.bookmark-'+post_id).fadeOut();
                $('.upb_bookmark_control_'+post_id).toggle();
            });
```

It shows the style button and everything but when i click on OK it doesnt perform the function above, nothing happens.

[image: Confirm]

So i rewrote it to

```
$(".upb_del_bookmark").click( function() {
        if(smoke.confirm(delete_message, function(e))) {
            if(e){
            var post_id = $(this).attr('rel');
            var data = {
                action: 'del_bookmark',
                del_post_id: post_id
            };
            $.post(upb_vars.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                $('.bookmark-'+post_id).fadeOut();
                $('.upb_bookmark_control_'+post_id).toggle();
            });
        }}
```

But now when i click it doesnt even show anything

I am not a programmer, Help!!!!!

If you want to try it go to latinunit.org login with david:123321 and then go to a post and try to add it to your favourites

**Update**

I tried the following, it shows the window but it doesnt perform the function;

```
$(".upb_del_bookmark").click( function() {
        smoke.confirm(delete_message, function(e) {
            if(e){
            var post_id = $(this).attr('rel');
            var data = {
                action: 'del_bookmark',
                del_post_id: post_id
            };
            $.post(upb_vars.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                $('.bookmark-'+post_id).fadeOut();
                $('.upb_bookmark_control_'+post_id).toggle();
            });
        }})
        return false;
    });
```

Here is the js file of the smoke script [Link](http://latinunit.org/smoke.js)

When i click on cancel the following shows;

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'callback' of object # is not a
>   function Line:198
>   Uncaught TypeError: Property 'callback' of object # is not a
>   function Line:208

The following is what's on those linesof the smoke script;

```
finishbuildConfirm: function (e, f, box)
    {
        smoke.listen(
            document.getElementById('confirm-cancel-' + f.newid),
            "click", 
            function () 
            {
                smoke.destroy(f.type, f.newid);
                f.callback(false);
            }
        );

        smoke.listen(
            document.getElementById('confirm-ok-' + f.newid),
            "click", 
            function () 
            {
                smoke.destroy(f.type, f.newid);
                f.callback(true);
            }
        );
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing a closing bracket/parenthesis `});`

Comment: Check for javascript errors in your browser, that will probably show you what is wrong.

Comment: _"which allows to style the classic alert javascript windows"_ - No it doesn't. The built-in alert/confirm functionality can't be styled, so smoke.js substitutes something similar, but (despite what the smoke.js webpage initially claims) it's not just a matter of adding `smoke.` in front of your `alert()` and `confirm()` calls, you actually need to restructure your code to allow for the asynchronous processing of the smoke functions.

Comment: @nnnnnn I agree, the smoke.js site is misleading and is contributing to the confusion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin javascript alert/confirm functions are synchronous, this is not. You need to handle the result of the confirm using the javascript callback pattern. You pass a function to the smoke.confirm() function which called when you need to respond to an action.

See the following code. The if around the smoke.confirm() has been removed and the handling code is wrapped in the function passed to the smoke.confirm() function.

```
$(".upb_del_bookmark").click( function() {
    smoke.confirm(delete_message, function(e) {
        if(e){
            var post_id = $(this).attr('rel');
            var data = {
                action: 'del_bookmark',
                del_post_id: post_id
            };
            $.post(upb_vars.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                $('.bookmark-'+post_id).fadeOut();
                $('.upb_bookmark_control_'+post_id).toggle();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I highly recommend reading a little about the callback pattern in javascript. It's very common and understanding it will help you use this plugin and many others.

Comment: The closing bracket for the if statement needs to go within the function, right?

Comment: Correct, I just copied the code, did not check the syntax. I've updated the example, cheers.

Comment: I tried your code but it doesnt do anything, i pasted what i rewrote again it was similar to yours except for the ending closet brakets and it shows the confirm window but it doesnt perform the rest of the code

Comment: Hi please check update question, the end bit contains the error codes

Comment: The second argument to smoke.confirm() must be a function. The error indicates this is not the case. I had a quick look on your site and the line <code>if(smoke.confirm(delete_message)==true) { </code> does not match my example. Again I recommend learning a little about javascript callbacks, it is essential to understanding how this will work.